# Nextjs page refresh always bring me to index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

I don't understand why when I refresh a page in my nextjs app, I always get back to the index page.
I have an e-commerce SPA with a catalogue page in index.js and and the products are displayed through the dynamic [name].js page. If I navigate through the browser refresh or back button, the routing is a mess. I think I miss something in the good practices of nextjs.

index.js

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Catalogue from "../../components/Catalogue";
import { getProducts } from "../../utils/api";

const HomePage = ({ products }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Catalogue</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Classe moyenne éditions publie des livres et multiples d'artistes, émergeants ou reconnus, en France et à l'international."
        />
        <meta
          name="keywords"
          content="Edition d'artiste, Livres, prints, multiples, art books, librairie, concept store, Bookshop, Bookstore"
        />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      </Head>
      <Catalogue products={products} />
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const products = await getProducts();
  return { props: { products } };
}

export default HomePage;
```

[name].js

```
const ProductPage = ({ product }) => {

  const router = useRouter();
  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <div>Loading products...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <Head>
        <title>
          {product.name} {product.author}
        </title>
      </Head>
      <div className="col right" key={product.id}>
        <div className="colophon" key={product.id}>
          <p>
            {product.annee}
            <br />
            Format : {product.size} <br />
            {product.pages} pages
            <br />
            {product.cover} <br />
            Printing : {product.printing}
            <br />
            Paper : {product.paper}
            <br />
            {product.copies} exemplaires
            <br />
            {product.price} € + Shipping
            <br />
            <br />
          </p>
          <div className="colophon">
            <p style= {{ 
              width: '50%',
              textAlign: 'end',
              color: '#6223f5' }}>
              The website is under maintenance. To order a book, please send us an email at <a href="mailto:hello@cmeditions.fr" style={{ textDecoration: 'underline' }}>Hello</a>
            </p>
            {product.status === true ? (
              <button
                className="snipcart-add-item buy-button "
                variant="dark"
                onMouseEnter={(e) => handleEnter(e)}
                onMouseOut={(e) => handleExit(e)}
                data-item-id={product.id}
                data-item-price={product.price}
                data-item-url={router.asPath}
                data-item-image={getStrapiMedia(product.grid_pic.url)}
                data-item-name={product.name}
                data-item-description={product.author}
                v-bind="customFields"
              >
                BUY ME!
              </button>
            ) : (
              <div className="text-center mr-10 mb-1">
                <div
                  className="p-2 bg-indigo-800 items-center text-indigo-100 leading-none lg:rounded-full flex lg:inline-flex"
                  role="alert"
                >
                  <span className="flex rounded-full bg-indigo-500 uppercase px-2 py-1 text-xs font-bold mr-3">
                    Coming soon...
                  </span>
                  <span className="font-semibold mr-2 text-left flex-auto">
                    This article is not available yet.
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div >
  );
};

export default ProductPage;

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const product = await getProduct(params.name);
  return { props: { product } };
}

// This function gets called at build time
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Call an external API endpoint to get products
  const products = await getProducts();
  // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
  const paths = products.map(
    (product) => `/books/${product.name}`
  );
  // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
  // { fallback: false } means other routes should 404.
  return { paths, fallback: false };
}
```

I read this on the nextjs doc, could it be part of the solution?..

> If the page uses an optional catch-all route, supply null, [],
> undefined or false to render the root-most route. For example, if you
> supply slug: false for pages/[[...slug]], Next.js will statically
> generate the page /.

Comment: If anyone can just explain me why on local refreshing is just refreshing me the page while in production it leads me to the / route ?

Comment: The only difference I found with the strapi e-commerce starter is the fallback : false (true in the starter). Could it come from that?

Comment: Am also noticing the exact same issue. Am using firebase for production. 
@Rom-888, Have you figured out a solution?

Comment: I also use firebase. I have the same problem again with another app ...

Comment: I tried by deploy on Vercel and the problem is solved. But actually, I don't know what was wrong with firebase ...

Comment: @Rom-888 same here guys. why is nextjs so complicated.

Answer (score 2):

The format of `paths` on `getStaticPaths` is wrong.

Here is the documentation.
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Call an external API endpoint to get products
  const products = await getProducts();
  // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
  const paths = products.map(
    (product) => ({ params: { name: product.name } })
  );
  // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
  // { fallback: false } means other routes should 404.
  return { paths, fallback: false };
}
```

---

UPDATE

---

I've tried your code on local and [CSB](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-firefly-xmmxz?file=/pages/index.js), and it seemed to work as expected.

You say it only happens in production environment, where are you deploying it?
There might be a problem in the deployment process, so you might want to contact your service provider.

Also, I'm wondering where you put the pages directory. nextjs requires the pages directory to be in the root or `src` directory.

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/src-directory

Comment: Thank you. But I still have the same problem on production. If I'm on a product page and click refresh, the url on the brower is still /books/[name], but on the screen, I'm back to the index

Comment: Mm... that's strange. Have you been build a custom server or using next server? And is the behavior occurs only on production or not?  `I read this on the nextjs doc, could it be part of the solution?` It's may not for you because the [name].js is not catch-all route.

Comment: I'm using the next server and yes, it only occurs on production. You're right for the catch-all. I already consider to build a custom server, but want to be sure it the best solution.

Comment: But according to nextjs, "most of the time, you will not need a custom server", my project is not so special. I don't understand what I did wrong..

Comment: It's deployed on firebase and the pages directory is in the root

Comment: This is happening in Firefox and safari, not in chrome in my case.

Answer (score 1):

For Basic NGINX Solving:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see the original question and the other answer - the problem is not related to nginx, nginx is not even used here.

Comment: thank you, Gaurang Thakker. This answer helped me in my nginx config or next.js. Even if it is not related to this question.